# Singleton with context in Android

Tags: java, android, singleton

I want to create a Singleton class that will be callable from all points in my application. The problem is this class will need a context for its operations.

I don't want to have to recreate the singleton in every activity because that way it looses all sense, so I thought about creating it in my MainActivity, with an init method where I pass the context as an argument. From that point on, my Singleton would be useable, but I think this is bad design because that way my MainActivity reference will always be held and thus I might run into memory leaks.

Am I right here?

Comment: If my Singleton object is static, and I'm holding a reference to the context, then that context is never garbage collected. If I'm not mistaken, this could cause a memory leak. If this is not the case, please expand a little bit on your answer.

Comment: Memory leaks *plural*? If it's a singleton then there's a single reference to its instance variables. How is this a leak, and even if it was, how would it actually *matter*?

Comment: Well, all the assets kept in the activity where I init my Singleton will be held all throughout the app execution. If for instance I have a big image there, it could easily fill in my memory and I could soon run out of it.

Comment: @MichelReap I thought you were passing the context, not your entire app.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are right not to save main activity context into the singleton because of memory leaks. If you need constant context inside your singleton, use getApplicationContext(). This can be safely saved. Note though that this context  is not useable for most gui-related functions. In rare cases you need activity level context inside singleton, pass calling activity context to singleton's method without saving

Comment: You mean, if I use getApplicationContext() on my init() method, I won't get memory leaking problems, whereas if I pass the activity reference directly (i.e. init(this) ), that's when I will get in trouble?

Comment: @MichelReap `this` is more than *just* a context.

Comment: Yes, trouble arises, when you save reference to an Activity's context outside your activity in application-scope storage. This prevents the activity to be destroyed when needed and leads to all kinds of improper context usage.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `WeakReference<Context>`:

```
private WeakReference<Context> context;

public static synchronized OsControler getInstance(Context context, int numero) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new OsControler(context, numero);
    }

    return mInstance;
}

private OsControler(Context context, int numero) {
    this.context = new WeakReference<>(context);
    NUMERO = numero;
}
```